# Can I use a 0.7A charger in place of a 1A charger?

Tags: voltage, current, charger

One problem that I usually come across is the current ratings on mobile phone chargers. Right now, I need a 1A charger (which was shipped with my phone) and I have a 0.7A charger handy. Both the chargers have a 5V output.

I read here [Charging devices - Voltage and Amperage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29259/charging-devices-voltage-and-amperage) that:

> Correct voltage rating and too low current rating may cause damage.
>   Slightly too low may be OK with computers an similar.

Now I am wondering:
1. What happens if I connect my phone to this charger ? Is it safe or will it cause problems later on?

**Misc:**
I have a 220V / 50Hz / Single Phase supply.
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S3 (if this is even relevant) and the charger I have is from Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini

Comment: Lover current should only result in a slower charging process.

Comment: @Gunnish Are you sure it wont harm ???

Comment: I've seen at least one USB charger that simply refused to charge too great of a load, shutting down entirely instead. But that was seven years ago.

Answer (score 2):

A one-time use should be safe.

But since you're dealing with Samsung, be careful. Their last Galaxy presented a few [problems](http://youtu.be/2QHd-_qncEU).

Answer (score 2):

There should be no problem. The device detects the highest current the charger is able to supply and adjust its internal resistor so the voltage is at an acceptable level. If the current is to low, the device stops charging.

If you notice that your device is constantly starting/stopping the charging process, you should disconnect the charger.